# Prestashop Paypal Payment Error

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, prestashop, payment, prestashop-1.5

When I make the payment with PayPal on my website with prestashop, after Checkout Payment, the page goes to a 404 error, and if I refresh I get this error:

```
Please try to contact the merchant:
<b>PayPal response:</b>
BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS -> 0
CHECKOUTSTATUS -> PaymentActionCompleted
TIMESTAMP -> 2014-05-26T11:37:21Z
EMAIL -> email@hotmail.com
PAYERID -> DMCCLG8Q5ZSX8
PAYERSTATUS -> unverified
FIRSTNAME -> Firstname Middlename
LASTNAME -> Lastname
COUNTRYCODE -> DK
SHIPTONAME -> Firstname Middlename Lastname
SHIPTOSTREET -> Adress
SHIPTOSTREET2 -> Adress
SHIPTOCITY -> City
SHIPTOZIP -> Zipcode
SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE -> DK
SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME -> Denmark
ADDRESSSTATUS -> Unconfirmed
CURRENCYCODE -> DKK
AMT -> 6.00
ITEMAMT -> 6.00
SHIPPINGAMT -> 0.00
HANDLINGAMT -> 0.00
TAXAMT -> 0.00
INSURANCEAMT -> 0.00
SHIPDISCAMT -> 0.00
L_NAME0 -> prøve item
L_NUMBER0 -> 29
L_QTY0 -> 1
L_TAXAMT0 -> 0.00
L_AMT0 -> 6.00
L_DESC0 -> lalala...
L_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0 -> 0.00000
L_ITEMLENGTHVALUE0 -> 0.00000
L_ITEMWIDTHVALUE0 -> 0.00000
L_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE0 -> 0.00000
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE -> DKK
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT -> 6.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT -> 6.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT -> 0.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT -> 0.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT -> 0.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT -> 0.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT -> 0.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TRANSACTIONID -> 81L157049P102883X
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED -> false
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME -> Firstname Middlename Lastname
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET -> Adress
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2 -> Adress
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY -> City
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP -> Zipcode
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE -> DK
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME -> Denmark
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSSTATUS -> Unconfirmed
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSNORMALIZATIONSTATUS -> None
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0 -> prøve item
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0 -> 29
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0 -> 1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0 -> 0.00
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0 -> 6.00
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0 -> lalala...
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWEIGHTVALUE0 -> 0.00000
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMLENGTHVALUE0 -> 0.00000
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMWIDTHVALUE0 -> 0.00000
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMHEIGHTVALUE0 -> 0.00000
PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID -> 81L157049P102883X
PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE -> 0
Cart changed since the last checkout express, please make a new Paypal checkout payment
Your cart is empty.
```

Anyone have any idea how to fix this? I'm using prestashop 1.5.6.1 with the Alysum Theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't ask for a Zip code on my website, and the module needed one thus getting a null value of some sort and making the request to paypal invalid. So I fixed the issue by making Zip Code required as an input on my website, and now the Paypal module works.

Answer (score 1):

"PAYERSTATUS -> unverified" in the response from PayPal indicates that there are issues that need to be addressed within the account. Take the steps necessary to verify the account and it should work as intended.

Comment: I propably should have added that the payment on Paypal goes through, it doesn't show the confirmation on the website correctly however. I'm not sure it's a fault with Paypal.